# QtCamera with Qt5.3.2

Tags: c++, qt, camera

I want to build a Qt Camera application on my ARM device by qml.

Now My Qt version is Qt5.3.2

To porting on my arm device ,I had changed  gstreamer source(imx*)  and sink(imx*) in qtmultimedia\src\plugins\gstreamer\camerabin

It seed to work, but it only contains one frame (fixed image)

qml source:

```
 import QtQuick 2.0       

 import QtMultimedia 5.0

      Rectangle {
            width: 640
            height: 480

            Camera {
                    id: camera
                   // imageProcessing.whiteBalanceMode: CameraImageProcessing.WhiteBalanceFlash
                    //exposure {
                          //  exposureCompensation: -1.0
                            //exposureMode: Camera.ExposurePortrait
                   // }
                //flash.mode: Camera.FlashRedEyeReduction
            }
    VideoOutput {
        source: camera
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus : visible // to receive focus and capture key events when visible
    }
}
```

I get the following warning and error

CameraBin error: "Internal data flow error."